# Wrong values in the parameters passed by rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I am trying to test a service but something wrong is happening when I pass the parameters to the service class, the values ​​are being passed in the wrong way by rspec.

My service is:

```
class CheckInvitesService
  def initialize(user, course)
    @user = user
    @course = course
  end

  def call
    if UserCourseRegistration.exists?(user_id: @user, course_id: @course)
      false
    else
      UserCourseRegistration.create(user_id: @user, 
                                    course_id: @course, 
                                    school_id: find_school)
    end
  end

  private

  def find_school
    school = Course.find(@course).school.id
  end
end
```

My test is:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe CheckInvitesService do
  describe "call" do
    context 'invite already exists' do
      it 'return' do
        @current_user_admin = create(:admin)
        @school = create(:school, user: @current_user_admin)
        @course = create(:course, user: @current_user_admin, school: @school)

        # puts @course
        # puts @course.id

        @verify = CheckInvitesService.new(@course.id, @current_user_admin.id).call
        expect(@verify).to be_falsey
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I printed `@course.id` and it returns: `122`

But when I call the service class, the parameter inside it has another value, for example the `@course.id`, i passed takes the value: `627`

I get the following error:

> Failures:
>
> 1) CheckInvitesService call invite already exists return
>        Failure/Error: school = Course.find(@course).school.id
>
> ```
>  ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
>    Couldn't find Course with 'id'=627
> ```

What is entering the class is another id of course the id 627 and not the 122 that should have been passed via parameter.

Comment: `CheckInvitesService.new(@course.id, @current_user_admin.id)` shouldn't be `@course.id` the second argument, and `@current_user_admin.id` the one for the `user` parameter?

Comment: Yes I typed wrong, but the error remains.

Comment: Could you add the return value of `puts @current_user_admin.id`?

Comment: _"What is entering the class is another id of course the id 627 and not the 122 that should have been passed via parameter."_ - @SebastianPalma's comment should solve this issue. If you still have another error, please update the question with that.

Comment: Why are your arguments called `(user, course)` and not `(user_id, course_id)` for obvious reasons?

Comment: Could you tailf the test.log when running this example? Just so we can see what is happening behind the scene.

Answer (score 1):

It appears your arguments are out of order.  CheckInvitesService has:

```
initialize(user, course)
```

But when you create the `CheckInvitesService` object, you're passing `course` as the first argument.

```
CheckInvitesService.new(@course.id, @current_user_admin.id).call
```

Should be

```
CheckInvitesService.new(@current_user_admin.id, @course.id).call
```

Comment: As per the OP's comment above, this doesn't fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find_or_create_by` in your service, it should work, too.

```
  def call
    UserCourseRegistration.find_or_create_by(user: @user, course: @course, school: find_school)
  end
```